# How to include a URL hyper link in JSON

Tags: json

I need to define a JSON filed value as URL link. How to achieve this.

Ex

```
{
"myurl":"<I need to give URL hyper link here>"
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your problem? Does your URL have some special characters? What is your programming language? Where does the value comes from -is it predefined (fixed) or comes from some variable? Where your json is defined, in your code or separate file?

Comment: @mpasko256 I have special characters  I need to hide the URL line with actual URL hiding and display text is Click Here

Answer (score 0):

Simply define your url value in anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

Let assume you code in pure html/javascript

To mage special characters:

1. Use `'` instead of `"` or use escape sequences `\'`
2. Use javascript builtin: `encodeURI`

Sample code:

```js
(function() {
  const json = {
    "myurl": 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53838312/how-to-inlcude-a-url-hyper-link-in-json?noredirect=1#comment94527886_53838312'
  };

  function getMyUrl() {
    return encodeURI(json.myurl);
  }

  function setupLink() {
    const linkId = 'link';
    const linkElement = document.getElementById(linkId);
    linkElement.setAttribute('href', getMyUrl());
  }

  function onReady() {
    setupLink();
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onReady);
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <a id="link" target="_blank">Click here!</a>
</body>

</html>
```